# Can I avoid copying during the intialization of a std::initializer_list without using raw pointers?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, initializer-list

Let's say I have several objects declared locally that I want to iterate over using range-based for syntax. This seems to work well, however, it appears that to put the local objects into the initializer_list, a copy is performed. This is bad news for objects like `std::shared_ptr` for which (as I understand) incrementing the reference count is an atomic operation. The only way I think this can be avoided is by using raw pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptrInt1 = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptrInt2 = std::make_shared<int>(2);
    /* in this loop, ptrInt1 and ptrInt2 are copied before they are binded
       to ptrInt, this is ugly since the reference counter needs to temporarily
       increased */
    for(const std::shared_ptr<int>& ptrInt : {ptrInt1, ptrInt2}) {
        std::cerr << *ptrInt << std::endl;
    }
    /* this solution works, but it feels somewhat ugly having to convert my smart
       pointers to raw pointers to avoid the copying, perhaps there is a better
       solution ?? */
    for(const int* rawPtrInt : {ptrInt1.get(), ptrInt2.get()}) {
        std::cerr << *rawPtrInt << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to iterate over a group of locally declared objects without copying them or resorting to using raw pointers?

Comment: It might be "bad" for e.g. `std::unique_ptr` which can't be copied, but I don't see the problem with `std::shared_ptr`. Yes a copy will be made, the reference counter will increase, but then the copy will be destructed and the reference counter will be decreased again. Why is this a problem?

Comment: I am a little bit confused about why incrementing the reference count being atomic is problematic. I mean I understand that you want to avoid the copy, but that applies in general not only for smart pointers whose reference count increment is atomic, or do I miss something?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it is a big performance hit in some cases, as this increase is atomic, and in many cases renders compiler optimizations unavailable.

Comment: @SergeyA exactly

Comment: well thats what I missed ;)

Comment: Make a helper function that returns an array of reference wrappers to your objects?

Comment: Instead of using a temporary array how about you do it the other way around? I.e. you put your shared_ptrs into an array/vector and then define `ptrInt1` as reference.

Comment: Then we come to the discussion about possible premature optimizations... Is this a *measured* bottleneck in your program? Unless it isn't one of the top two (or possibly three) bottlenecks then my suggestion is to not bother. First of all concentrate on writing good, clean, easily understandable and maintainable code that doesn't need comments due to optimization-obfuscation. If the measured "efficiency" doesn't match requirements (and remember that "good enough" often *is* good enough), then profile and measure to find the bottlenecks to concentrate your effort on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude disagree wholeheartedly. For example, in my line of business, this is simply unacceptable approach, and code should be optimized from the ground up. It could be 'an approach', but please do not overgeneralize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to build a list of `std::reference_wrapper`s.  This hides the pointer and lets you write the list like

```
for(const std::shared_ptr<int>& ptrInt : {std::ref(ptrInt1), std::ref(ptrInt2)}) {
    std::cerr << *ptrInt << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @JeJo `move` would be destructive and `cref` is redundant.

Comment: @JeJo Do you mean using something like `for(auto& ptrInt : {std::cref(ptrInt1), std::cref(ptrInt2)})`

Comment: @JeJo Ok.  That's redundant.  `const std::shared_ptr<int>& ptrInt` already gives you a reference to const so adding the `c` to `ref` is just typing you don't have do.

Comment: `auto ptrIntRef : {std::cref(ptrInt1), std::cref(ptrInt2)}` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Unfortunately that won't compile as the type of `ptrIntRef` becomes `std::reference_wrapper<const std::shared_ptr<int> >`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9d2610005d6f19a

Comment: Not ideal [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de8bb145e0440425) your version seems so better.

Comment: @Jarod42 What would be really nice is if the overloaded the `operator <<` and `operator >>` and just had it forward to the correct type.  Really they should have that for all the operators.  Maybe I'll write a paper for that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small function template that extends [@NathanOliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54869137/9593596) and reduces some of the typing.

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>

// No rvalues, thanks to @NathanOliver for pointing that out:
template <class ...T>
auto crefRange(const T&&...) = delete;

template <class ...T>
auto crefRange(const T&... args)
{
   using First = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<T...>>;

   return std::array<First, sizeof...(T)>{{std::cref(args)...}};
}
```

You can instantiate and call it via

```
for(const std::shared_ptr<int>& ptrInt : crefRange(ptrInt1, ptrInt2))
    std::cerr << *ptrInt << std::endl;
```

This will fail if you instantiate it with different types, but this limitation is identical with the `std::initializer_list` approach.

Comment: This is actually a little dangerous as is.  `auto crefRange(const T&... args)` will accept temporaries so you build an array of dangling `reference_wrapper`s.  I believe you can fix it by using `template <class ...T>
auto crefRange(T&... args)` and then adding `template <class ...T>
auto crefRange(T&&... args) = delete;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point, admittedly I haven't thought about it. The rvalue overloads of the `std::cref` template are explicitly `delete`d, though - the burden of handling this case is hence already covered (and passing temporaries to `crefRange` won't compile).

Comment: Unfortunetly in `crefRange` `args` is a lvalue since it has a name so it is not covered.  see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fdf8924ff4ee548 (it works but it doesn't have to)

Comment: @NathanOliver You're right, `args` is a lvalue... mh - why does it give me `copying array element [...] invokes deleted constructor` upon `std::cref(args)...` then, when invoking as `crefRange(std::make_unique<int>(42));`?

Comment: Ah, I missed it.  `return std::array<First, sizeof...(T)>` says make an array of the first element passed so in the first case it was shared_ptr's and in my case it was int's.  It wasn't an array of reference wrappers.  So it is trying to copy the unique_ptr into the array.  You need something like `return std::array<decltype(std::cref(std::declval<First&>())), sizeof...(T)>{{std::cref(args)...}};` to get an array of references and then that seg faults: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2454421e2f1a5cf

Comment: @NathanOliver I see, thanks for the hint. I need to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `std::initializer_list` is badly suited for this task. Since

> The underlying array is a temporary array of type const T[N], in which
>   each element is copy-initialized...

(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list), it is going to perform copies, and compiler won't elide them.

For this task, I would do something else. Probably create a compile-time variadic template class templated of pointers to underlying objects. Let me know if you'd like some code.